# Own Chapter and section

Tags: sectioning, lists, enumerate, sections-paragraphs

I know there are probably tons of question *like* this but I cant figure the whole out for myself.

I'm searching for an way of defining own chapters or sections in an only slightly bigger font like:

**1.** First exercise

**1a.** First part of exersice

---

- Being able to use them in headers (like chapters)
- Auto numeration (also 1a.   1b.  ...)

Comment: This does rather look like a `theorem` etc. like environment than a new sectioning level structure. The precise implemenation depends somewhat on the document class. And you provided not a starter document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following more or less solves your problem.

The things are very easy if you use the [titlesec](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec?lang=en) package.

Here is the relevant code. You want to control the numbering of chapter, section and subsection (I took the liberty of adding it). Then you control how these are displayed. Perhaps you want to control the spacing as well.

You can carry out the necessary tweaks to suit your taste.

For more information on the commands, please read section 3.1 and 3.2 of the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf).

---

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{titlesec}

% Control number formats
\def\thesection{\arabic{chapter}\alph{section}}
\def\thesubsection{\arabic{chapter}\alph{section}(\roman{subsection})}

% Control display formats
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{}{\large\thechapter.\ }{0.0mm}{\large}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{}{\large\thesection.\ }{0.0mm}{\large}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{}{\thesubsection.\ }{0.0mm}{}

% Control spacing
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0.0mm}{\bigskipamount}{\medskipamount}
\titlespacing{\section}{0.0mm}{\medskipamount}{\smallskipamount}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0.0mm}{\smallskipamount}{\smallskipamount}

\parindent 0.0mm

\begin{document}

\chapter{First exercise}
This exercise in on\dots

\section{First part of exersice}
In the first part you need to answer\dots

\section{Second part of exersice}
The second part has a number of subparts\dots

\subsection{Second One}

Please tell us\dots

\subsection{Second Two}

And tell us\dots

\end{document}
```

---

[image]